# Cordova button doesn't work on android 9, newbie needs

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, button

I was just trying to make a button(id="clickme") links index.html and js/buttonexample.js. I saw the button but it doesn't work. I tried both on browser and android emulator.

js/buttonexample.js

```
document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click", msg());
function msg() {
        alert("good"); 
}
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/buttonexample.js"></script>
<div><Button id = "clickme">click</Button></div>
```

with reference to [Cordova: onclick event is calling before button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860274/cordova-onclick-event-is-calling-before-button-click)
I also tried

```
document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click", msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button id = "clickme">click</Button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/buttonexample.js"></script>
```

put button above script without the brackets after mag

```
document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click", msg);
    function msg() {
            alert("good"); 
    }
```